# Splunk Query using multikv

Tags: macos, testing, splunk

when doing the following search to see what applications are installed on a OS X system, there are duplicate rows.

Applications that have spaces in them will partially end up in the VERSION column:

```
sourcetype=package | multikv | stats values(VERSION) by NAME
```

does anyone know how to parse the data to remove the duplicates, or how to use 'multikv' to have it not sort the data in such a way where the columns display the data correctly

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you're working on? I think that will help get you an answer.

Comment: @GGordonWorleyIII Thanks for the suggestion... some more banging of my head against the keyboard got me the result.

Answer (score -1):

sourcetype=package NAME| multikv noheader=true | stats values(VERSION) AS "Version Number" by NAME